# Koma-Script | Book Class | Title Page: Author's Name Before Book Title

Tags: titles, koma-script

I want the author's name to appear first on the title page.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\subtitle{My Subtitle}
\author{John Doe}
\date{}

\maketitle      

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should really create your own titlepage in a book.

Comment: Use the `\begin{titlepage}` environment and create your own custom title page.

Comment: @TeXnician Same idea within 6 sec :)

Comment: I use `\uppertitleback{}` to design the back of the title page. Does this affect somehow the use of `\begin{titlepage}`?

Comment: `https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script` --> `scrguien.pdf` --> `Page 272` --> `\begin{titlepage} . . . \end{titlepage}` "With the standard classes and with KOMA -Script, all title pages are defined in a special
environment, the titlepage environment."

Comment: `\begin{titlepage}` is "just" an empty page that you can design as you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could patch `\maketitle`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% remove author below the title
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}
  {%
    {%
      \usekomafont{author}{%
        \lineskip 0.75em
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          \@author
        \end{tabular}\par
      }%
    }%
    \vskip 1.5em
  }
  {}{}{\PatchFailed}
% insert author between subject and title
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}
  {%
    \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
      {\usekomafont{subject}{\@subject\par}}%
      \vskip 3em
    \fi
  }
  {%
    \ifx\@subject\@empty \else
      {\usekomafont{subject}{\@subject\par}}%
      \vskip 3em
    \fi
    {%
      \usekomafont{author}{%
        \lineskip 0.75em
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          \@author
        \end{tabular}\par
      }%
    }%
    \vskip 1em
  }
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\subtitle{My Subtitle}
\author{John Doe}
\uppertitleback{Upper Text}
\lowertitleback{Lower Text}
%\date{}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you can use the `titlepage` environment. Note that it is also possible to insert content on the back of the title page.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \null\vfill
  \begin{center}
    {%
      \usekomafont{author}{%
        \lineskip 0.75em
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          John Doe% <- author
        \end{tabular}\par
      }%
    }%
    \vskip 1em
    {%
      \usekomafont{title}{\huge
        My title% <- title
      \par}%
    }%
    \vskip 1em
    {%
      \usekomafont{subtitle}{%
        My subtitle% <- subtitle
      \par}%
    }%
    \vskip 1.5em
    {\usekomafont{date}{\today \par}}%
    \vskip 0pt plus 4fill
  \end{center}
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    Upper Text% <- upper text
  \end{minipage}\par
  \vfill
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
    Lower Text% <- lower text
  \end{minipage}\par
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\myTitle}{Title of Document}
\newcommand*{\mySubtitle}{SubTitle of Document}
\newcommand*{\myAuthor}{FirstName Surname}
\newcommand*{\myDate}{\today}

\title{\myTitle}
\subtitle{\mySubtitle}
\author{\myAuthor}
\date{\myDate}

\maketitle    

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\myAuthor{}\\ 
% {} is important if you have a text right after the command. 
% Otherwise the command will "eat" the blank space.
\myTitle\\
\mySubtitle\\
\myDate
\end{titlepage} 

\end{document}
```

> Based on an answer from the author of the KOMA classes, see [here](https://komascript.de/node/869)
>   (in German).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%\maketitle`?

Comment: I just compare the different outputs and show that you still can use the standard command if needed.

Comment: `\date` sets `\@date` which is used inside `\maketitle` to print the date.

Comment: @esdd Thanks! Your comment made me realize that I confused `\date` with `\today`. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a quick and dirty solution:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\subtitle{My Subtitle\vspace{-8\baselineskip}}
\author{John Doe}
\date{}

\maketitle      

\end{document}
```