# Possible incompatibility between xpatch and hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, xpatch

I have lately been creating custom classes, and found that one of my desired commands, `\xpatchcmd`, did not work on some occassions. I spotted that loading of package `hyperref` is the culprit.

For reference, I'm referring to [this answer's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413698/53868) application of `\xpatchcmd`, which I implemented in my own MWE:

### Intended outcome (without loading `hyperref`)

In the minimal setup it works as intended, giving the horizontal rule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\@date}{\@date\par\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: horizontal rule is added as expected]

### Unexpected outcome (with loading `hyperref`)

If I additionally load `hyperref`, then the patch does not apply:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\@date}{\@date\par\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: no horizonal bar. This is not expected.]

### Further thoughts

- I have found this behaviour is not limited to documentclass `article`. The same **unexpected** results are obtained with e.g. `scrbook`.
- I am intentionally loading `hyperref` as the last package. Even changing the order of `` xpatch`and `` hyperref`` did not change the behaviour.
- I found no incompatibilities between either packages mentioned in their respective documentations.

### Question

How can I load `hyperref` **and** get the desired patch working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `hyperref` is loaded, the definition of `\maketitle` changes; this happens for a lot of standard commands. The original meaning is stored in `\HyOrg@maketitle`.

However, it's *not* `\maketitle` that you want to patch, but `\@maketitle`. Your patch worked just by chance (and actually broke something, not very important, though).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}
 {\end{center}}
 {\\[1ex]\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\end{center}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Adjust the vertical space (here `1ex`) to suit your taste.

[image]

Note that the definition of `\maketitle` in the `article` class is

```
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    [...irrelevant code...]
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
    \global\let\thanks\relax
    \global\let\maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@maketitle\relax
    \global\let\@thanks\@empty
    \global\let\@author\@empty
    \global\let\@date\@empty
    \global\let\@title\@empty
    \global\let\title\relax
    \global\let\author\relax
    \global\let\date\relax
    \global\let\and\relax
}
```

and `\@date` is not used elsewhere by this code. The command that's really responsible for the typesetting of the title is `\@maketitle`:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that loading ``hyperref`` changes the definition. However, I am not really interested in the ``article`` class only, but in working around/with this change in arbitrary classes. Take, e.g. ``scrbook``, where I also want to be able to inject code. There, ``\maketitle and  ``\@maketitle`` are more convoluted, but yur example for the ``article`` class was sufficient in getting me towards the right path.